# Defining Equivalence relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

So I am not really comfortable with equivalence relations, so this example from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Examples) gives me trouble. Here is what it says:

Let the set $\{a,b,c\}$ have the equivalence relation $\{(a,a),(b,b),(c,c),(b,c),(c,b)\}$.

So it can also be $\lbrace(a,a), (b,b), (c,c) \rbrace$ if I so choose?

Comment: Yes, that is an equivalence relation, too. In fact, a little meditations shows that an equivalence relation on a set is essentially the same thing as a partition on the set.

Comment: @Travis So the equivalence classes depend on which equivalence relation I choose?

Comment: @SalmonKiller Yes, that is exactly right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your relation is indeed an equivalence relation:

Reflexivity clearly holds, as symmetry does. Transitivity does hold since

$$\forall x,y,z\in X: xRy \wedge yRz \implies xRz $$

is a true statement: $xRy \wedge yRz$ is true in this case if and only if $x=y=z$, in which case clearly (reflexivity) $xRz$.

**EDIT: Simpler argument (without symbolic logic)**

You want to prove that the relation $R=\lbrace(a,a), (b,b), (c,c) \rbrace$ defined on the set $X=\{a,b,c\}$ is an equivalence relation, so you must prove three properties:

1. For every $x\in X$, $(x,x)\in R$.   **(Reflexivity)**
2. For every $x,y\in X$, if $(x,y)\in R$ then necessarily $(y,x)\in R$ **(Symmetry)**
3. For every $x,y,z\in R$, if $(x,y)\in R$ and $(y,z)\in R$, then necessarily $(x,z)\in R$. **(Transitivity)**.

We now prove those properties.

1. Take any element $x$ of $X$, we have only three possibilities, namely $x$ equals $a$, $b$ or $c$, in any case, $(x,x)\in R$ so the relation is reflexive.
2. Take any element $x$ and $y$ of $X$, we must prove that if $(x,y)\in R$, then $(y,x)\in R$. We only need to focus on the cases where $(x,y)\in R$ (if $(x,y)\notin R$ there's nothing to prove!), so the only cases are $x=y=a, b, c$ where the symmetry clearly holds.
3. Here's the point, we must take any three elements $x,y,z$ of $X$ and prove that if $(x,y)\in R$ and $(y,z)\in R$, then $(x,z)\in R$. Again, we only focus on the case $(x,y)\in R$ and $(y,z)\in R$, but this happens only if $x=y=z$ and therefore, clearly, $(x,z)\in R$.

Please notice *not every* relation you define on $X$ becomes an equivalence relation. For example, if you choose to add (only) $(a,b)$ to $R$, then symmetry is lost.

Comment: Can you please explain that same idea without symbolic logic? I would really appreciate that.